# Flutter Admob with ios WebView

Tags: flutter, admob, flutterwebviewplugin

I built a flutter App and successfully added firebase_admob, and the Android deployment went well, the App works as intended.

Currently I am finalizing the iOS deployment, the admob banner is shown and all is fine.

However once I load a screen with webview component the Admob banner disappears and doesn't show again, even after the refresh time has passed.

I tried requesting a new admob banner in the new webview screen, but it doesn't show as well.

Is there any known conflict between firebase_admob and webview in iOS?

here is how I call the Admob banner, nothing special though.

```
class MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
////
    bannerAd = BannerAd(
          adUnitId:BANNER_AD_ID,
          size: size,
          listener: banner._eventListener,
        );

    bannerAd    
      ..load()
      ..show(anchorType: AnchorType.bottom);

///
}
```

Comment: Are you showing `WebView` in full screen?

Comment: inside a scaffold with AppBar and BottomNavigationBar.

Comment: Does banner ad shows above `BottomNavigationBar` (when you are not using Webview)?

Comment: Yes, banner ad always shows on top of everything else. In fact I use the BottomNavigationBar as a placeholder for the banner so other scrollable items don't hide below the banner.